# Return Contents of XML Document for IF Statement

Tags: xml, vb.net

I've got an xml document that lists the current state of a web controlled relay that I would like the run an if statement on. The contents of the document look like:

```
<datavalues>
<relaystate>0</relaystate>
<inputstate>0</inputstate>
<rebootstate>0</rebootstate>
<totalreboots>0</totalreboots>
</datavalues>
```

I am needing to be able to return each of those rows into my code and run an if statement as needed for the data. I've tried doing a reader.Read() and a print on the content with no avail as I'm sure this is incorrect.

```
    If reader.GetAttribute("relaystate") = 1 Then
        relayState.Text = "ON"
    Else relayState.Text = "OFF"

    End If
```

Any help in the right direction on how to return this result set would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to read element values, not attributes. This code assumes that you have a string variable named filename that points to the file.

```
    Dim doc As New xmldocument
    doc.Load(filename)
    Dim relayState As Integer = CInt(doc.SelectSingleNode("/datavalues/relaystate").Value)
    Dim inputState As Integer = CInt(doc.SelectSingleNode("/datavalues/inputstate").Value)
    Dim rebootState As Integer = CInt(doc.SelectSingleNode("/datavalues/rebootstate").Value)
    Dim totalReboots As Integer = CInt(doc.SelectSingleNode("/datavalues/totalreboots").Value)
```

Then you can use the state values this way:

```
    If relayState = 1 Then
        relayState.Text = "ON"
    Else : relayState.Text = "OFF"

    End If
```